# Keep div visible when the mouse is over it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `div2` that fades away after 3 seconds and appears again on `div1` or itself hover.

The problem is that it fades away again after 3 seconds and I want it to remain active while the mouse is over it.

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // div2 fades away after 3s
    setInterval(function(){ 
        $(".div2").addClass("fade-away");
    }, 3000);
  
    // div2 pops up on hover
    $(".div1, .div2").hover(function(){
        $(".div2").removeClass("fade-away")
});
});
```

```css
.div1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
}

.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -70px;
  background: lightblue;
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-away {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

<div class="div1"></div>

<div class="div2"></div>
```

Is there a way to make the div2 remain active while the mouse is over it with javascrit and css only? Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a boolean flag to do it.

Set the boolean to true when mouseenter and set it to false on mouseleave event.

https://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/0nc2bw8f/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    let mouseIn = false;
  // div2 fades away after 3s
  setInterval(function() {
    if (!mouseIn) {
        $(".div2").addClass("fade-away");
    }
  }, 3000);

    $('.div1').on('mouseenter', () => {
    mouseIn = true;
  });
  
  $('.div1').on('mouseleave', () => {
    mouseIn = false;
  });

  // div2 pops up on hover
  $(".div1, .div2").hover(function() {
    $(".div2").removeClass("fade-away")
  });
});
```

```css
.div1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
}

.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -70px;
  background: lightblue;
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-away {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

<div class="div1"></div>

<div class="div2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and easy way to do it.
You can do it by hovering over any class, I just did it in text for the example.

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
    
.myDIV:hover + .hide {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
<h2>Display an Element on Hover</h2>
<div class="myDIV">Hover over me.</div>
<div class="hide">I am shown when someone hovers over the div above.</div>
</body>
```